# Jdk or headless version ? Which should I use for Hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop

Which version of java should I use for Hadoop installation ? Jdk or headless version ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use jdk for installing hadoop. In the hadoop-evn.sh file set `export $JAVA_HOME=jdk path`. 
You can check the path using `readlink -f $(which java)`